# Visual Studio 2019 problem building OpenSource project SuperSlicer. git failures

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Attempting to build the dependencies for this project fail on about 5 of the 15 or so targets of this part (deps) of the project.

It seems all of the failures are related to git. getting errors of the form:

```
2>fatal: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe: 'C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe' is outside repository at 'C:/Users/marcel/Repos/SuperSlicer/deps/build/dep_ZLIB-prefix/src/dep_ZLIB'
```

These are all related to git patch commands in the CMAKE files.
Note that the target directory for this is one that was just successfully cloned in the previous step...
CMAKE files have the following defined:

```
prusaslicer_add_cmake_project(ZLIB
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
  GIT_TAG v1.2.11
  PATCH_COMMAND       ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} checkout -f -- . && git clean -df && 
                      ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} apply --whitespace=fix ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/0001-

Respect-BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.patch
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DSKIP_INSTALL_FILES=ON         # Prevent installation of man pages et al.
    -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
)
```

So, the clone operation works fine, the checkout option seems to work fine, clean works fine but the "apply" command fails

Been scratching my head about this for about a week now... still no clue... does anyone have any ideas?

If I run the equivalent git commands from the shell, using the full path to the target, it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the latest candidate for cmake 3.2.0rc3 may have a bug.  I guess I was just too bleeding edge...
It seems to identify the git executable as:
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

so, that doesn't work well.

I reinstalled cmake version 3.19.6 and now it works much better... :-)